# Install gfortran-4.9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have the following Warning:

```
Warning: you need to install gfortran-4.9 echo  to allow for Matlab 
and CUTEst interaction.
```

So I tried to install gfortran-4.9 using the command

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.9
```

receiving the following output error

```
 E: Unable to locate package gfortran-4.9
 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gfortran-4.9'
 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gfortran-4.9'
```

(I tried to add several repositories looking at other threads).

Could someone help please?
Best Regards
Stefano

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. If you are sure that you added a repository that contains `gfortran-4.9` for bionic (18.04), please tell us which repository it is. Keep in mind that many PPAs don't provide packages for bionic yet.

Comment: This seems like a Mathworks support question more than an Ubuntu question.

Comment: @danzel Thank you very much for your reply! No, I am not sure I added the good repositories; the problem is this, I can not find references to these repositories, if they exist. How can I check their existence of gfortran-4.9 for bionic?

Comment: You can search the repositories online [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com). gfortran-4.9 is not available for bionic, but gfortran-5 is, maybe that works.

Comment: @danzel Thank you very much for your precious help!